# Вызов функции при POST/GET отправке формы в PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос:
Есть форма для отправки сообщения:

```
<form name="message" method="" action="">
<p><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45"> </textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

но я не хочу создавать отдельный php файл для ее обработки. а хочу, чтобы у меня был один файл functions.php, где я описываю все функции. а при отправке вызвалась нужная функция send_message(). 
как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: или описывать эту функцию в этом же файле и вызывать $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']? Но все-таки хотелось бы держать все функции в одном месте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="message" method="post" action="functions.php">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="submit_form1" />
</form>

functions.php:
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit_form1']))
{
    ...
}
?>
```

Вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: а если в functions.php будет send_message(), то это будет выглядеть так: send_message(){if(isset($_POST['submit_form1']))
{
    ...
}
}
?
и функция вызовется, да?

Comment: Нет, это будет скорее выглядеть как function send_message(){...} 
if(isset($_POST['submit_form1'])){send_message();} А сама по себе функция не вызовется.

Comment: отлично! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше отправь форму на ту страницу которая нужна, а там при получении отправь на проверку в функцию. Например код будет выглядеть примерно так. 
File.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['button']))
    {
    send_message($_POST);
    }
?>
<form name="message" method="" action="">
<p><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45"> </textarea></p>
<p><input name="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

Если такой вариант не подходит то тогда JS тебе в руки.

```
<form name="message" method="" action="">
<p><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45"> </textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" onclick="send_message()" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

На submit вешаем вызов JS функции onclick="send_message()" а там в JS отправляем в файл functions.php и возвращаем ответ

Answer (score 0):

обычно делается так:

```
<form name="message" method="" action="">
*<input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_message"/>*
<p><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45"> </textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

PHP

```
switch( @$_REQUEST['action'] ){
    case 'send_message':
        .....
    break;
    case 'send_other_message':
        ....
    break;
    .....

}
```